# Creating hdf5 file with best parameters using Google Colab in Google Drive

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, hdf5, hdf

I'm trying to create a hdf5 which is included epoc, loss, and accuracy information by using Google Colab, and Google Drive.

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

filepath = '/models/{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-{val_loss:.4f}-{mae:.4f}-{val_mae:.4f}.hdf5'

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', save_best_only=True, mode='min')]


optimizers.SGD(momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=5, callbacks=callbacks, batch_size=16)
```

I shared a simple code example above, I'm not getting an error in the code, but there is no hdf5 file created in google drive.

Do I need to create the empty hdf5 file under a certain folder beforehand in Google Drive?

Comment: Do you call `model.save(filepath)` after you fit your model?

Comment: I did `model.save('filepath')` then when I run `!ls filepath` I'm able to see `saved_model.pb`. I could run `new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('filepath')` but still I couldn't see where is the those hdf5 files in Google Drive. Do I need to create manually ?

Comment: I don't know where Google Drive will save it. Probably in the current directory of your program. Add these lines to get that: `import os; print(os.getcwd())` THAT's where you should look. Good luck.